# Can't use "startIcon" & "endIcon" from <Button/> API of Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my simple React code for a single component but it keep throwing the same warning every-time I checked. Even when copy and past the example still same warning and the icon is nowhere to be seen. Please help!

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsBta.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';


class AddWorkButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }
    render() { 
        return (  
            <React.Fragment>
                <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="secondary"
                        startIcon={<AddIcon/>}
                >
                    TEST
                </Button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default AddWorkButton;
```

Comment: Warning: React does not recognize the `startIcon` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `starticon` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element ...

Comment: Which example you try? Can you send link?

Comment: I made a demo on code sandbox, but it works just fine
https://cpim7.csb.app/

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#buttons-with-icons-and-label Here I tried the button with icons and label one. Hmm I will try a new project and maybe it will work out normally like it should

Comment: Are you using version `4.5.0`?

Comment: Yes the latest one. Something must have gone wrong back then cause I try new one but nothing happen? 
Pretty sure I install every set-up needed for the last project but .... Suggest trying to move all the stuff when encounter this trouble.

Comment: My solution to this problem was to upgrade from version `4.3.1` to `4.5.1`. This library changes so fast its hard to keep track of it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error.

The problem on my side was that `react-script start` was already running when I updated the Material-UI package to 4.5.

After I have restarted the `react-script start` everything just started to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" >
          Send <ArrowForwardIcon /> </Button>
```

Not sure which way is the correct but I got it working this way,

Answer (score -1):

The startIcon and endIcon properties await the entry of a
element of type React.ReactNode, which itself is a React.ReactElement. That is, just use React.cloneElement().

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" startIcon={React.cloneElement(<SendIcon/>)}> TEST </Button>
```